# What would mammoth meat and milk taste like?

Tags: food, domestication

In my book series, there is this planet called Ryu 108. This is a very cold planet, with a southern continent resembling Norway and a northern continent resembling Iceland. The civilization inhabiting this cold planet is basically a fantasy counterpart culture of the vikings, but with one exception: they have domesticated woolly mammoths and they have become a quintessential part of their society.

There are many different mammoth breeds: some are bred for war, some for wool, others for milk, also a few for ivory, but many have been bred specifically for meat.

My question is how would these "meat mammoths" taste served on a plate next to a drinking horn full of mammoth milk in the dining hall of a space viking longhouse?

Comment: I am afraid this is opinion based. Apart from the conjecture on the real taste (whatever real might mean in this context) how are you going to pick the best answer?

Comment: Asking what does cockroach milk taste like is more feasible than this question, but well, who will volunteer?

Comment: We should of all messed around and been like. Well mammoth meat tastes like mammoth meat, what else do you expect it to taste like. or just been like Chicken.

Comment: I would say that what the animal is eating, its age and which part of the animal you're eating is more important for the taste than the breed. See [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/63786/what-biological-factors-affect-a-meats-taste). Your mammoth steak is going to taste like a steak from any animal that lived in cold climate. Same for milk.

Comment: It would taste like childhood and nostalgy.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is how would these "meat mammoths" taste served on a plate next to a drinking horn full of mammoth milk in the dining hall of a space viking longhouse?

Very similar to African elephant meat and milk except probably more fatty since they'd be bred for size and are not wild animals.

Comment: Not so sure, they are eating pretty different stuff.

Comment: @Legisey Local steak here in the tropics tastes the same as steak from the South island of New Zealand, so does the milk... same with the pork and the chickens.. the difference is mostly in fat content and tenderness since our animals aren't farmed in the same way.... unsure how you get a different taste unless you have some actual experience with mammoth meat

Comment: Well, for milk, this is probably due to industrial processing of it (pasteurization). Lot of taste from the meat comes while cooking. So cooking reduce the taste difference between two steaks.

Comment: @Legisey you think the space vikings are eating raw mammoth? From your comment above my answer, deer, sheep, goats and cows all eat the same thing in a cold climate in New Zealand, yet their meat is distinctly different to each other and similar to the same animals in warmer climes. We don't have venison here, but I can vouch for all the rest.

Comment: No, that's what I'm saying. If you're given a plate with Mammoth steak in it. If you're not told you're going to eat it and think "what a nice steak" and assume it was beef or horse or whatever. But the taste will not surprise you. Taste of meat will never surprise you. I tried crocodile, bison, ostrich, horse, beef, ... and they all taste more or less alike. The taste of spices that are used when cooking might surprise you.

Comment: @Legisey I can tell each meat apart, I haven't tried anything exotic, but have never been confused

Comment: @Legisey, I second Kilisi. I have had cow, horse, fox, buffalo, deer, and each was different. If they taste the same I would say you are being scammed, paying deer for a cow.

Comment: Cattle meat (raised) in Southeast Asia tastes different than the USA. Not sure if this was a water buffalo issue or what animal the meat usually came from or if it was based on the animal's diet (probably a mixture of all that). If I wanted something that tasted normal to me, I needed to buy something imported from Australia or similar